# py2neo run call gds.graph.drop

Tags: py2neo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgYF1.png)

When I run cypher 'call gds.graph.drop'
it will raise py2neo.errors.ProtocolError: Cannot decode response content as JSON
Are you meet this error?

Comment: seeing as you new on SO, could you please specify the versions of neo4j and py2neo you using.

Comment: I believe strongly that your issue, is caused by imcopartibility btn your version of neo4j and py2neo. py2neo lags behind neo4j releases. If you are using a neo4j of 5.3.0, it is most likley not compartible with py2neo, the current pre-release version still only accommodates version 4.4